# Panel data 'binary' treatment with multiple 'odd' start and end times

Tags: r, econometrics, panel-data, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I am investigating the impact of a county-level policy on crime outcomes. I am using a two-way fixed effects estimator. My exposure (i.e., treatment) is a static binary variable. The binary treatment dummy switches on and off for some units. Of the subset of treated counties, some were exposed multiple times, and some were exposed only once or twice. I do have a large subset of "never-receivers" as well. I observe all counties across 120 months. Here are my concerns.

The policy variable turns on and off at rather odd times. In other words, treatment might 'turn on' (i.e., switch from 0 to 1) for some counties for several months before switching off (i.e., treatment reverses). For a subset of adopter counties, treatment might begin on March 1st 2005 and end on June 30th 2005. Now, in the following year, some counties were treated again—but the intervention starts on April 14th 2006 and ends on August 7th 2006. This pattern repeats with irregular on and off periods.

In previous evaluations I have assessed county-level crime outcomes *across months*. But with the irregular exposure periods, I suppose I could disaggregate the time dimension to a lower level such as a weekly series. However, doing so introduces more 0 counts across weeks. This isn't necessarily a problem, but using a linear model to assess crime *rates* (i.e., a log-transformed crime rate) becomes problematic.

**Question 1**: Should I simply disaggregate down to a smaller sub-unit of time (i.e., week/day) so the main treatment dummy better delineates each intervention's start and end time? If I use a county-month panel then I won't capture all treatment epochs precisely, which deliberately introduces measurement error.

**Question 2**: Some crime outcomes show low cardinality across weeks. Assessing a log-transformed outcome with many zero counts will likely affect estimation if I use a linear panel data model. Thus, I suppose if the county-week panel is the way to go then I should substitute the linear model with a Poisson model and use the residential county population size as an offset. Any thoughts? My decision to do this is rather ad hoc.

**Question 3**: A model like the one I am proposing will, in theory, get a lot of feedback from the previous period. I don't necessarily want to add a lagged version of the *outcome* on the right-hand side because I am aware of the dangers. But, is it safe to argue that some of the endogeneity concerns wane as $T$ gets very large? Also, what concerns do I face by including a second order lag only? The basic specification is below:

$$
\text{log}(y_{it}) = \theta y_{i,t-1} + \sum_i\text{County}_i + \sum_t\text{Week}_t + \delta \text{Policy}_{it} + \text{log}(\text{Pop}_{it}),
$$

where $y_{it}$ is a very rare crime outcome; it is even more rare, so to speak, if I use a weekly time series. The right-hand side includes a lag of that outcome, fixed effects for counties and weeks, respectively, and the main policy variable. The last term is simply a population offset.

In sum, the lag might introduce more problems than it alleviates. I also found few fixes, in practice, using `glm()` or `pglm()` in R.

If it's of any help, I mainly work in R and the `lubridate` package is my best friend.